# Is this known to be equivalent to epimorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In *Algebra: Chapter 0*, Aluffi asks the reader to, on his or her own, "formulate a notion of epimorphism" which does not make reference to "elements" of a set. The definition I came up with was this:

> A function $f: A \to B$ is an epimorphism iff for all sets $Z$ and all functions $\beta : Z \to B$ there exists a function $\alpha : Z \to A$ such that $f \circ \alpha = \beta$.

Using this definition, it appears that a function $f$ is an epimorphism iff it is a surjection. I was rather dismayed when I looked in Awodey's *Category Theory* and found that his definition of epimorphism was different:

> In any category $C$, an arrow $f : A \to B$ is called a... epimorphism, if given any $i$, $j : B \to D$, $if=jf$ implies $i=j$.

Is there a name for what I have come up with other than "epimorphism"? Are epimorphisms ever defined in the way I did?

Comment: What you have defined is equivalent to the notion of a split epimorphism. In the category of sets every epimorphism is split, but that is not the case job other categories, e.g. abelian groups

Comment: Don't write "on his or her own"; write instead "on his own", which is the only grammatically correct alternative.

Comment: @AlexG. post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. I checked Awodey and CFTWM for information on split epimorphisms but didn't find anything illuminating; do you happen to have an (accessible) reference?

Comment: @MPW Strictly speaking, they're both "grammatically correct", though you may dislike the more prolix turn of phrase. This is not http://english.stackexchange.com, and certainly it is not axetogrind.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @BrianO: No, they are not, and shame on you for propagating that "apologetically gender-neutral" nonsense. You know as well as I do that masculine grammatical gender doesn't imply that "the reader" is a male.

Comment: @MPW Sorry to bear bad news, but indeed they are. "On his or her own" and other "his or her" constructs may be redundant, often awkward, and can provoke gratuitous outbursts of pedantry; but you know as well as I do that they are perfectly well-formed. You can have the last word in this exchange if you like: clearly we're both capable of flaming on for quite some time, but this is not the proper forum for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have defined is equivalent to the following notion of a *split epimorphism*:

> A morphism $f: A \to B$ is a *split epimorphism* if there exists a morphism $s: B \to A$ (called a *section* of $f$) such that $f \circ s = 1_B$.

Note that a split epimorphism is indeed an epimorphism, so the name is justified.

In the category of sets, a function is an epimorphism if and only if it is surjective. Moreover, every epimorphism is a split epimorphism. This is in fact equivalent to the axiom of choice.

This is not the case in other categories. For instance, in the category of abelian groups, the quotient homomorphism $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/ 2 \Bbb Z$ is an epimorphism. However, the only homomorphism $\Bbb Z/ 2 \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ is the one which sends both elements to zero. This is obviously not a splitting of the first homomorphism.